# Extracting relevant data from CAD format into a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, elevation, autocad

I have received some survey information in the format of a .DWG (AutoCAD file) and I am trying to extract the data from this file into QGIS and then into a PostgreSQL database.

In the .DWG file there are a number of linestrings that have 3D geometry (differing x,y and z values), but when importing into QGIS only the first z value is used for the remaining x and y values of that linestring. (some of the linestrings have up to 100 different vertices, all with different x,y,z values. But when imported, only one z value is used for the whole linestring)

Is there a way to extract each individual z value that corresponds to the correct x,y value?